# why is automaton with a queue is more powerful than an automaton with a stack?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

what is the logic behind this statement that with the use of queue the automaton becomes more powerful , is it that in a queue , we may do operations from both the ends as compared to a stack so it is equivalent to a turing machine ,therefore ,it is more powerful .

Comment: I think that most of the logic here will pertain mostly to the computer science understanding of "queue" and "stack" and would put this question on stackoverflow instead...

Comment: @abiessu Probably not — the question has a home here. My guess is that the proof involves exhibiting a language accepted by a queue automaton which is known to be not context-free (accepted by a stack machine *aka* PDA).

Comment: The logic is: [queue automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_automaton) are equivalent to Turing machines, while stack automata, i.e. PDAs, accept only context-free languages, which are a strict subset of the context-sensitive languages, which are in turn a strict subset of the decidable languages, and thus of the semi-decidable languages. It *turns out* that simply generalizing the stack of PDAs to a queue brings a lot more computational power — so much, that the resulting class of automata are Turing-complete. // Beyond these obvious(?) conclusions, I'm not sure what more you'd want.

Comment: The problem is the one that prevents ${a^nb^nc^n}$ from being context-free: You can only use stored information (the number of $a$) once (to count the $b$s and so then you can't count $c$s). Whereas with a queue, you can use it and immediately put at back in the queue to not forgetting it, while still being able to read the rest of the information.

Comment: Intuitively: with a stack, you can't read the stored data at the bottom of the stack without first popping and forgetting the data at the top.  With a queue, you can read any piece of data without forgetting any of the rest of it.

Comment: @xavierm02 Yes the classic example of a non-CFL, accepted by the very natural queue automaton you described. That language is also accepted by a 2-stack automaton, which has instructions instructions for pushing/popping one stack, the other stack, or both.

Comment: I got my answer ,thankss to all for your explanation.